# Receive UK visa vignette from a different visa centre

Tags: uk, standard-visitor-visas, australia, applications, vfs-global

Is it possible to have the UK visit visa vignette be obtained from a different visa center?

I applied for a UK visa (in progress in Sydney) but I'll be travelling next week to Schengen country and want to receive it in a different location?

Comment: AFAIK this is not an option. You can pay a fee to get your documents couriered to your home or work https://www.vfsglobal.co.uk/au/en/premium-services/courier-service but there’s no mention of collecting your visa in a different country altogether. Have you contacted VFS Global to ask?

Comment: OP has not returned to clarify about VFS. Putting on hold.